# 7475 IC strange behavior

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, flipflop

So I'm trying to make a shift register with the 7475 IC /4-BIT BISTABLE LATCHES/.
The problem is that the single latches doesn't seem to switch their states properly.
I'm using this schematic:

> ```
>         PART OF A 7475
> (Set)-----|D1    Q1|------[LED]--|
> (Enable)--|C    !Q1|X            |
>       |---|GND  VCC|---|         |
>       |                |---------|
>       |                |
>       |-[5.05V supply]-|
> ```

The IC uses positive TTL logic.
I'm expecting that the LED will turn on when the 'Enable' and 'Set' inputs go HIGH(+5V on them).
But nothing happens.Instead when 'Set' is LOW, the LED glows slightly and in any other case it's off.  Is the IC burnt up or I'm wiring it wrong?

Comment: Why do you expect that? The datasheet tells you it will light (Q=0) when D=0. And RawB's answer is right - you DO need a series R, 330 ohms to 1K.

Answer (score 4):

Yo will need to have a series resistor one the LED since LED's are current mode devices and are some what less compliant wrt to Voltage.  To size that properly you need to know the LED forward voltage, maximum current and also the maximum current possible out of the IC.  Additionally if you what the light to go on when Q1 is high then the current must flow from the pin through aLED resistor combination and into ground.  You have it wired to the Vcc.  When Q1 is high there is no voltage drop across the LED.

There are similar posts around that will show you how to size the resistor.

Comment: WHat current do you estimate he was actaully driving the LED without Rs? and How bright would you expect that to be? This was not explained but the solution is simple.

Comment: The LED is ok.Its internal resistance is 68ohm and at 3V the current that the latch provides is enough.My problem is that the flip-flop can't switch its state.When I turn it on there are 3V on the output and they won't become 0V if I connect D1 and C to VCC.How am I supposed to make the initial high level low and vise versa?